# How i can print single element of object array in PHP?

Tags: php, google-maps, object

I found class to convert address to GPS longitude/latitude with Google API.

I can print all array : `print_r($geo->adress(my address)`.

It will show

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [location] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [lat] => 53.1243946
                    [lng] => 18.001958
                )

            [city] => Bydgoszcz
            [street] => MarszaĹka Focha
            [number] => 4
            [code] => 85-070
        )

)
```

But I can't print single element. I need add location -> lat / lng to variables, but i can't convert object to string. How can i do this?

```
$lat = implode(",", $geo->adress('Focha 4, Bydgoszcz'); // doesn't work at all.
```

---

```
<?php

echo "<pre>";
$geo = new GeoGoogle;
print_r($geo->adress('Focha 4, Bydgoszcz'));
echo"</pre>";



final class GeoGoogle {

  // zwróć listę lokacji pasujących do podanego adresu
  function adress($adress) {
    return $this->parse(
      $this->prepare(
        'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='
        .urlencode($adress)
        .'&sensor=false'
      )
    );
  }

  // zwróć listę lokacji pasujących do podanej długości i szerokości
  function latlng($lat,$lng) {
    return $this->parse(
      $this->prepare(
        'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='
        .$lat .','. $lng
        .'&sensor=false'
      )
    );
  }

  /* pomocnicze */

  private function prepare($uri) {
    return json_decode( file_get_contents($uri) );
  }

  private function parse($data) {
    if($data->status == 'OK') {
      $results = array();
      foreach($data->results as $res) { // przetwórz wyniki
        $result = array(
          'location' => null,
          'city' => null,
          'street' => null,
          'number' => null,
          'code' => null
        );
        // pobierz współrzędne
        if(isset($res->geometry)) {
          if(isset($res->geometry->location)) {
            $result['location'] = $res->geometry->location;
          }
        }
        // pobierz dane
        foreach($res->address_components as $component) {
          foreach($component->types as $type) {
            switch($type) {
              case 'street_number':
                $result['number'] = $component->long_name;
                break;
              case 'route':
                $result['street'] = $component->long_name;
                break;
              case 'postal_code':
                $result['code'] = $component->long_name;
                break;
              case 'sublocality':
                $result['city'] = $component->long_name;
                break;
              case 'administrative_area_level_3':
                if(is_null($result['city'])) {
                  $result['city'] = $component->long_name;
                }
                break;
            }
          }
        }
        if(!is_null($result['city'])) {
          $results[] = (object) $result;
        }
      }
      return $results;
    }
    return array();
  }
}
```

Comment: You **can't** use `implode` here because the value you are trying to access is an object.

Comment: user3712744 wants to know "does echo $res[0]->location->lat work?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get 'lat' and 'lng' values from your object, try this:

```
$lat = $object->location['lat'];
$lng = $object->location['lng'];
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/3TBY9dDL)

Edit: Looking closer at your data, this might be more helpful:

```
$lat = $geo[0]->location['lat'];
$lng = $geo[0]->location['lng'];
```

[**See demo 2**](http://codepad.org/j2Z4KK9F)

Edit: in regard to error stated in comment `Cannot use object of type GeoGoogle as array`

Try this:

```
$my_geo = $geo->adress(my address);

$lat = $my_geo[0]->location->lat;
$lng = $my_geo[0]->location->lng;
```

Comment: This might work, but you need to know if the properties are public, or if there is a `__get` method defined.

Comment: @BrettSantore Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't the properties of a `StdClass object` public by default?

Comment: Mark M is right. `stdClass` has all public dynamic properties. The second set of calls is the correct one that you want.

Comment: I have no problem with @mark-m being right, we are here to provide the best answer, I was unable to find documentation to support that, can someone please provide it?

Comment: @BrettSantore You're right, there doesn't seem to be much documentation on the topic - the closest I can find is [**this**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php), which says that class properties not declared as *public*, *private*, or *protected* will default to *public*. So if a property is declared simply without a specific visibility, it is treated as public. I think that alone answers the question - but for me, experiment is the best [**proof**](http://codepad.org/RD6F8WWE).

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type GeoGoogle as array in C:\WebServ\httpd\bdg\content\admin\adres.php on line 8, doesn't work ;/

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\WebServ\httpd\bdg\content\admin\adres.php on line 9, when i use demo2